# What does this wording of pointer type means in C99?

Tags: c, c99

In C99 6.2.5 P27

> All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements
>   as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and
>   alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same
>   representation or alignment requirements.

What does this mean?

> All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.

And what is the reason for this exception?

> Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

I'd appreciate an explanation with relevant examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you can store any pointer-to-structure value in any other pointer-to-structure variable, and in the process you create a valid pointer object, and you can recover the original pointer from the intermediate variable. By contrast, you are *not* allowed to use a pointer of a different category as an intermediate. For example:

```
struct Foo * p = &x;   // x is a struct Foo
struct Bar * q;

memcpy(&q, &p, sizeof p);  // OK, it's allowed to read (but not dereference!) q
memcpy(&p, &q, sizeof q);  // OK, p is now the same it was before

union Zip * r;
int       * s;

// not allowed to do the same with (p, r) and (p, s)!
```

The `memcpy`s are OK because both `p` and `q` have the same size and alignment, because they are both pointers-to-structs. The same is true for two pointers-to-union, or for two pointers-to-int, but you cannot mix categories.

Here's another, very contrived, but valid example:

```
struct Foo { int a; };

int f(struct Bar * p)
{
    return (struct Foo *)(p)->a;
}

int main()
{
    Foo x = { 12 };
    return f((struct Bar *)(&x));
}
```

This program would *not* be valid if the function parameter of `f` were a pointer of a different category (say a pointer-to-union or pointer-to-int).

The only pointer type that *any* object pointer can be converted to and back is `void *`. (So we could have made the parameter of `f` a `void *`. This is arguably the most common style. But it's conceivable that making it a struct pointer is more efficient and thus preferable on some platforms.)

Comment: Thanks! The contrived example is quite good:)  And in the last question the **Pointers to other types ...** means that pointers of different category couldn't cast back and forth freely, rather than that pointers to **the other types** need not have the same representation or alignment requirement, am I right?

Comment: @larmbr: err.. yes, I think so. I'm not entirely sure I'm getting you. But for example if an `int *` had a weaker alignment than a `struct Foo *`, and if I had used an `int *` for the argument type in the contrived example, the the cast might have tried to create a struct pointer that wasn't aligned correctly. This could lead to a total crash.

Comment: Aha, I think you are getting me . Please see my quetion below Daniel Fischer's answer and maybe you can give me answer either. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

It means that casting pointers to a structure type to pointers to another structure type is just a reinterpretation.

Generally, it is allowed that pointers to different types have different sizes, and different alignment requirements, so e.g. a `char*` might have a size and alignment requirement of 16 and store the address big-endian, but an `unsigned long long*` only a size and alignment requirement of 8 and store the address little-endian.

But for `struct foo *` and `struct bar *`, the representations and alignment requirements must be identical. (Similar for `union`s.)

One reason is that it is common to have pointers to incomplete `struct`s in `struct`s. If the representation and alignment requirements of structure pointers were not identical, that would be impossible.

Comment: Thanks! The last paragraph in your answer gives a quite reasonable explanation. But why not STANDARD mandates that all types of pointer are of same size and have unique representation ? Though it may be less space-efficient, but it makes sense since pointer value is just a location in the virtual memory space a process conceives, it fits in a fix-width type in a specific machine.

Comment: @larmbr: Turn it around: Why *should* the standard impose such a needless restriction? It doesn't help anyone (if you want a pointer for anything, you already have `void *` for that purpose), and it may well preclude implementations from using the most natural representation.

Comment: @larmbr: see the [Intel memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model), still supported today; in particular, function pointers and data pointers normally used a different representation, and data pointers could be explicitly qualified to to get a [far pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer); I do not know if there actually was an architecture that did decide pointer representation of data pointers by type instead of qualifier

Comment: @Kerrek SB. 1)Yep, We do have omnipotent `void *`, but for the sake of type safety, we have other types of pointers. Isn't that the all-same -size-and-same-alignment-requirment  pointers a good thing? 2) Maybe that will preclude implementation, but is there any archs have different pointers of diffrent size ? Plz name it. Even though there is ,I think this may be sort of silly no to make it all the same size, otherwise some narrow-width type could not access some space that is valid for the process.

Comment: @Christoph: Much of the griping about the Intel memory model, IMHO, stems from language limitations.  With a language designed to work with it (e.g. a pointer that uses two bytes to identify a segment and assumes an offset of zero), the segmented architecture could have allowed for more efficient code than would be possible in a 32-bit linear address space (note, btw, that the "original" Macintosh OS has a lot of 32K limits in places where the PC would have 64K limits, even though it uses a 32-bit CPU)

Comment: @Christoph: Actually, my biggest "regret" regarding segmentation is that the 386 defined "full" pointers as 16-bit segment plus 32-bit offset.  If they were instead 32+32, even if they'd simply been analogous to the 8086 segments, an application could have had a 64GB addressing space while using 32-bit object references rather than 64-bit ones.  If the segmentation was a little fancier, the address space could have been even bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Different pointer types may have different sizes and representations; IOW, an `int *` may have a different size and representation from a `char *`, which may have a different size and representation from a `double *`, etc.

Pointers to any `struct` type will have the same size and representation; IOW, `struct T *` and `struct Q *` will look the same.  Similarly for unions, `union T *` and `union U *` will look the same (although they may look different from `struct` pointers).

Comment: On the other hand, any pointer has to be convertible to `void *` and back, which means that a common representation for every kind of pointer must be possible.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: except for function pointers, which need not be convertible to `void *`

Comment: @Christoph: Double-indirect function pointers which hold the addresses of actual function pointers would, however, be convertible to `void*` on any implementation, regardless of how the function pointers themselves are stored.

Answer (score 1):

In informal language, the important parts of C language semantics with regards to pointer representation and conversion are:

- void and character pointers share a representation
- all structure pointers share a representation
- all union pointers share a representation
- arbitrary object pointers (but in general not function pointers) can be converted to 
  void or character pointers and back to their original type
- arbitrary function pointers can be converted to other function pointer types and back to their original type

Everything else is up to the implementation.

The necessity for these particular rules can be justified like this:

Conversion of object pointers to character pointers allows bytewise access regardless of type. While void pointers are basically character pointers in disguise, they carry a different semantic connotation (a generic pointer without type association).

Structure resp. union pointers sharing representations makes pointers to incomplete types (opaque pointers) possible.

Function pointers may not be converted to void pointers as they may reside in an altogether different address space and may not be available for bytewise access. They are convertible among themselves as there is no generic function pointer type (the equivalent of void pointers) and will probably share a single representation. As far as I know, the single representation is not required by the C standard, ie in principle casting between function pointer types may involve an actual conversion. However, because non-prototype functions (and thus corresponding function pointers) need to be compatible to a whole range of function types, possible conversions are severely limited.

In general, the C standard leaves a quite a lot up to implementations to accomodate a wide range of historical precedence without artificially restricting future development.

Comment: In what cases would conversions among function-pointer types be useful?  I have to struggle to come up with any examples that even remotely make sense (e.g. a list of of pairs of functions, where the first function in each pair always has the same signature, and the second function is called by the first); even in those cases, I think it would be just as easy to have an array of `void*` which contains the addresses structs of various types that all contain paired functions.

Comment: @supercat: there's no `void*` equivalent for function pointers; if you want to store pointers to arbitrary functions, you'll need to choose a prototype and do explicit conversions; not converting back to the correct type before calling the function is of course UB

Answer (score 0):

It means you can, for instance, not rely on the structure or alignment of, say, function pointers.  I'd assume this also means you can make no such assumptions when dealing with pointers to C++ `class`es or `struct`s (although I didn't check how C++ defines these).